# appcmd.exe causes IIS service to drop

Tags: powershell, iis, service, appcmd

I am using **appcmd.exe** to add IP addresses to the ipSecurity module of IIS. I am using a very basic Powershell script which reads a list from a web service of no more than 10-20 IPs, and I am adding those into the ipSecurity. I then run my Powershell through Task Scheduler, every 5 minutes to keep this list updated.

The command I am using via Powershell to add the IPs is

`& $appcmd set config  -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress='$ip_address',subnetMask='$subnet_address',allowed='False']" /commit:apphost | Out-null`

Perhaps it's important to say that on every execution of my Powershell, I am clearing first this list entirely using this command.

`& $appcmd clear config /delete:true /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /commit:apphost | Out-null`

and then I add the new, updated IP list.

When I do this, I have noticed that the IIS service may drop. It does not happen always. But sometimes it does. When I stop the scheduler my IIS service works like a charm.

Any help? I couldn't find anything related at the Microsoft pages to be honest.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried doing it without explicitly clearing the existing settings? Try removing the `+` in from of the new ip entry and then run it without clearing

Comment: Hm.. but how am I going to keep my list short , without removing the IPs I don't want to to use any more? I just want to maintain a list of 10-20 IPs maximum.

Comment: When the IIS service drop? Clear all IPs or add new IPs? Try to monitor the moment when service drop to check if it is caused by appcmd.

Comment: @BruceZhang it's caused by AppCmd 100%. But not always. If I run my Powershell manually, and I keep refreshing IIS , I cannot detect anything.

However, when I deploy this script to 3-4 servers , as we have web monitoring tools installed, I can see that the service is dropped (times out) for a few seconds.

Comment: What is the performance of service drop? Application pool restart, application pool recycle or high cpu usage and high memory?